# Move at an angle, jquery, animate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a way to specify the angle when using

```
$(this).animate({'left': '+=30px'}, 1000);
```

I would like

```
$(this).animate({'48': '+=30px'}, 1000);
```

the 48 would be the angle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify both `left` and `top` property:

```
$(this).animate({left: '+=30px', top: '+=30px'}, 1000);
```

In this case, the angle would be 45°.

To specify a different angle, first calculate cos(α) and sin(α). The cosinus specifies how far you have to go right, and the sinus how far to go up, to make a distance of 1 pixel in the specified angle. If you want to cover 30 pixels distance instead, multiply the sinus and cosinus results by 30.

Comment: doesnt sin(45) and cos(45) = .7071067812

Comment: Just in case the second paragraph doesn't make sense: http://jsfiddle.net/SMvj3/3/

Comment: @thelost: After having calculated sin and cos, you can multiply both results with the same factor to specify the distance. As sin(45°)=cos(45°) and left=top, the angle is indeed 45°.

Comment: Yogu's example would move about 42px at a 45 degree angle. To move 30px at 45, you would have to `Math.cos(Math.PI/4)*30`.

Comment: i have a question, why are we multiplying by 30

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to correct a mistake in 32bitkid's otherwise excellent example from the best answer by Yogu.

If Math.PI is divded by -180 (instead of 180) it will result in the correct position for the div. 90 degree angle was moving div down instead of up.

```
$(function() {
    var dist = 30;
    var angle = 90;
    var x = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/-180) * dist;
    var y = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/-180) * dist;
    $("div").animate({'left': '+='+x+'px', 'top': '+='+y+'px'}, 1000);      
})
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yL8hxnz/